# Parse callback after Oncreate and how to pass data to Fragments

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, callback, fragment

When I use Parse Query to retrieve data from Parse DB, I found that data existed after Oncreate() all executed but I need to pass the retrieved data to the FragmentAdapter in order to pass data to the three Fragments, and set the corresponding textView.

These are part of the code inside Oncreate()

```
try {
            loadData();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        initSpinner();
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.detail_tab_viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null){
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.detail_tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

These are codes of loadData(),
JD and Req are declared in this way in a AppCompatActivity class called "InternDetailActivity":
final List JD = new ArrayList();
final List req = new ArrayList();

The problem is I need to set the FragmentPagerAdapter and pass the List JD and req with data to the three fragments after Parse callback, but not before the Parse callback. I set the Toast.makeText to see the sequence of code run and it is wrong in order. the List of JD and req size keeps zero during Oncreate() even i called loadData(). Please explain why as I am not professional programmer but I am willing to learn the basic concept. And any suggestion..., Thanks!!~

```
public void loadData() throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setMessage("Loading Data");
    pd.setIndeterminate(false);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    Thread LoadData = new Thread(){

    public void run(){
        try{
            ParseQuery<Jobs> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(type);

            query.getInBackground(InternDetailActivity.this.job_id, new GetCallback<Jobs>(){

                            @Override
                            public void done(Jobs Jobs, ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Log.v("TESTING INSIDE 1", Integer.toString(JD.size())); 
                            if(e==null){                    
                            JD.add(Jobs.getDescription());
                            req.add(Jobs.getReq());
                            MainApplication.tempjd = Jobs.getDescription();

                            if(e==null && Jobs.getList("Comment")!=null){

                                Log.v("Check Array",Jobs.getList("Comment").get(0).toString());
                                if(Jobs.getList("Comment").size()>0){
                                  for(int i=0;i<=Jobs.getList("Comment").size()-1;i++){ 
                                  gossip.add(Jobs.getList("Comment").get(i).toString());
                                  }
                                }
                            }

                            else{


                            }

                            }

                            else{


                            }


                            pd.dismiss();

                            }
            });


        }
        finally{
            interrupt();
        }       
    }};

    LoadData.start();


}
```

setupViewPager code:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new GossipFragment(), "Gossip");
    adapter.addFrag(new JDFragment(), "JD & Req");
    adapter.addFrag(new PrepareFragment(), "Preparation");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter code, I think people should be very familiar with this, haha

```
static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the Parse update from in the fragment.

Do the ArrayAdapter for the VP in the same fragment.

Consider using a 'ViewHolder' pattern with the adapter ( google it)

Use a Model or the idea of a Model as common object collaborates with:

Parse Insert

Parse Callback ( if necessary for getting OID into the model )

Model to Array, Array Element to ViewHolder thats used by Adapter

On a CallBack from parse insert, call a function that inserts a model's required attribute into the Adapter's Array. Depend on adapter type you may have to use special "insert() " method .

Then, call the "notifyall()" on the adapter.

It should all just work.